# jsp file with two forms and one submit button

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

You may think that this question is duplicated, it is not because I had made some research and tried them in my code without getting a result. I need to submit two forms with one button but the button is not working. The code is as below:

```
    <form:form id="cruiseform" modelAttribute="shipcruise" action="cruisepage" method="post" 
        style="padding:2px;background:#F0F8FF;width:50%;border-top:2px solid #009;
        border-bottom:2px solid #009;border-right:2px solid #009;border-left:2px solid #009;margin-left:350px;border-radius:10px">

                        ** <form:label path="cruiseName">Cruise Name</form:label>

                        <form:input path="cruiseName" type="text" name="cruiseName" required ="required"/>

                        <form:label path="startDate">Start Date</form:label>

                        <form:input path="startDate" type="text" name="startDate" placeholder="e.g 2020/1/4"  required ="required" />

                        <form:label path="endDate">End Date</form:label>

                        <form:input path="endDate" type="text" name="endDate" placeholder="e.g 2020/1/4"  required ="required" />

                        <form:label path="destination">Destination</form:label>

                        <form:input path="destination" type="text" name="destination" placeholder="Eg. 2 hours" required ="required" />**

                 </form:form>
```

the other form :

```
                  <form:form id="bookingform" modelAttribute="bookcruise" 
                 action="cruisePage" 
                method="post" 

                  style="padding:2px;background:#F0F8FF;width:50%;border- 
              top:2px solid #009;
                     border-bottom:2px solid #009;border-right:2px solid 
              #009;border-left:2px solid 
                   #009;margin- 
                      left:350px;border-radius:10px">
                 <form:label path="stateroomType"> State Room Type</form:label>

                        <form:input path="stateroomType" type="text" name="stateroomType" required ="required"/>

                        <form:label path="totalAmount">Price</form:label>

                        <form:input path="totalAmount" type="text" name="totalAmount" required ="required" />

                        <form:label path="totalGuests">Number of Guests</form:label>

                        <form:input path="totalGuests" type="text" name="totalGuests"  required ="required" />
                   </form:form>
```

buttons:

```
                  <button type="button" onclick="submitForms()" value="submit"
                   style="width:100%;border-radius:10px;text-shadow:2px 2px 3px 
                   rgba(150,150,150,0.75);font-family:time">Confirm Your Booking?</button>

                        <button type="button" value="reset" onclick="resetForms()"
                        style="width:100%;border-radius:10px;text-shadow:2px 2px 3px 
                        rgba(150,150,150,0.75);font-family:time">Clear</button>
                   <a href="index.jsp">Cancel</a>

                    <a href="customer?passengerId=${passengerId}">Modify your profile</a>
```

javascript code:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function submitForms(){
             document.submitforms[0].submit();
             document.submitforms[1].submit();
         }

         function resetForms(){
             document.submitforms[0].reset();
             document.submitforms[1].reset();
         }
```

Comment: in your `js` code you have typo i.e : this `documnet`  should be `document`.

Comment: Thank you for noting that, but the javascript code is not working as I had coded it. I have applied the solution you mentioned and still not working

Comment: can you post your `html` generated code for `forms` ? Also. does your console shows any error ?

Comment: Yes, it says --> No mapping for GET /myproject/js/scripts.js

Comment: Updated the forms as you requested @Swati

Comment: does your js code is on same page ? or it is in `script.js` file ?

Comment: it is on the same page as the forms and the buttons

Comment: change your `function` like this `function submitForms() {
  document.getElementById("cruiseform").submit();
  document.getElementById("bookingform").submit();
}` and check if that works.

Comment: It is not working @Swati

Comment: Not enough reputation to go for chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209688/discussion-between-swati-and-tasy-androes).